# Python: How can I remove excel entries via openpyxl using a feedback loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I am building a small app to study the vocabulary of various languages (see below the code for Mandarin). I have the basic funcions which work well. Now I want to add a button in my GUI where i can remove entries (i.e. individual words) from the database, once i have mastered the word (i.e. a button in tkinter which would remove the entry). After removing, the random function in python should then only select words from the reduced database. Do you have any idea how to do this? Any help is welcome!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import sys
import os
randvalue_start = random.randint(2, 592)

window = Tk()
window.title('Mandarin Vocabulary')
window.geometry('500x400')
icon = PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Mandarin\HSKlogopng.600px.png')
icon2 = icon.subsample(5 ,5)
label1 = Label(window, image = icon2, anchor="ne")


import openpyxl
path = r"\Users\PycharmProjects\Mandarin\characters.xlsx"
worbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, read_only=True)
sheet = worbook.active
row_count = (sheet.max_row)


def english_btn1():
    global randvalue_start
    english = f"B{randvalue_start}"
    english_value = sheet[english].value
    label_eng = Label(window, text=english_value+":", width=20, height=3, font=("TkDefaultFont",15))
    label_pin = Label(window, text="", font=30, width=15, height=3)
    label_mand = Label(window, text="", font=30, width=15, height=4)
    label_eng.grid(row=8,column=1,rowspan=2)
    label_pin.grid(row=8, column=2)
    label_mand.grid(row=9, column=2)

def pinying_btn2():
    global randvalue_start
    pinying = f"C{randvalue_start}"
    mandarin = f"D{randvalue_start}"
    pinying_value = sheet[pinying].value
    mandarin_value = sheet[mandarin].value
    combined = f"{pinying}'/'{mandarin}"
    combined_value = f"{pinying_value}'/'{mandarin_value}"
    label_pin = Label(window ,text=pinying_value,font=("TkDefaultFont",15), width=10, height=2)
    label_mand = Label(window,text=mandarin_value,font=("TkDefaultFont",30), width=8,height=2, borderwidth=5,relief="ridge")
    label_pin.grid(row=8,column=2)
    label_mand.grid(row=9,column=2)
    randvalue_start = random.randint(2, 592)

def reset():
     os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)

frame = LabelFrame(window,text="Input",padx=5, pady=5)
frame.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


btn2 = Button(frame,text = "Show answer", fg = "green" ,width=20 ,command=pinying_btn2)
btn3 = Button(frame,text = "clear", fg= "red", width=20 ,command=reset)
btn1 = Button(frame,text = "Next character", fg = "black" ,width=20,command=english_btn1)
words_label = Label(frame,text = "# of characters: " + str(row_count))



label1.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan=2)
Label(window, text="", width=20, height=3, font=("TkDefaultFont", 15)).grid(row=8, column=1)
label_blk1 = Label(window, text="", font=("TkDefaultFont", 15), width=10, height=3).grid(row=8, column=2)
label_blk2 = Label(window, text="", font=("TkDefaultFont", 30), width=10, height=2, padx=1, pady=1).grid(row=9, column=2)

btn1.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
btn2.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
btn3.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
words_label.grid(padx=5,pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question about Pyxl or Excel. The question is really: how do you generate random numbers that skip certain numbers.

```
from random import randint
n = 592

numbers = list(range(n))

# To get a random number from the list
random_number = numbers[randint(0, len(numbers)-1)]

# To remove 123 from the list
numbers.remove(123)
```

Comment: thats a very elegant idea - thank a lot for your help!